# How to get parent element by specified tag name using jquery?

Tags: jquery, parent

I want to get an Element's parent which has an specified tag name.

Sample code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='button' id='myId' />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now i want something like this:

```
$('#myId').specificParent('table'); //returns NEAREST parent of myId Element which table is it's tagname.
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

See [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

I.e.,

```
$('#myId').closest('table')
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/bp8EA/1/))

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#myId').closest("table");
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('#myId').parents('table')` works as well